# Rewrite custom wordpress parameters

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx

I try to rewrite wordpress url's with parameters, like:

from: http://www.url.com/person/?fname=billn&lname=gates

to: http://www.url.com/person/jason/gates/

from: http://www.url.com/company/?name=microsoft&country=usa

to: http://www.url.com/company/microsoft/usa/

Where person & company are wordpress pages and Fname, lname, name and country are custom $_get parameters.

I tried some things (without results) like:

```
rewrite ^/page/bill/gates/(.*)$ /index.php?p=6&fname=$1&lname=$2 last;
```

I currently using the default Wordpress config for Nginx:

```
    server {
            listen   80; 
            listen   [::]:80 

            root /var/www;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    }
```

Comment: only with `/page` urls ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady In this case: yes

Comment: do you have an `index.php` inside `/page` ? or do you want to use the same `/index.php` at root ? cause in the example you used `http://www.url.com/page/?name=jason&type=human`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady The 'index.php?p=6' part are standard Wordpress rewrite rules for nginx. The trick is to override them and make my rewrite rules work.

Comment: my question was to understand if you're going to use the same index file or if you created a new one inside the a `/page` directory

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can try to append the args to the wordpress args, like this

```
location ^/page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ {
    try_files /index.php?$args&name=$1&type=$2 =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for one of my sites to do that for all links.

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/fonts/(.+)$ /system/application/fonts/$1 last;
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
            break;
    }
}
```

So for only just page.. maybe you could try:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
            break;
    }
}
```

Edit: PHP rewrite rules from Nginx.. http://www.farinspace.com/wordpress-nginx-rewrite-rules/